# Adobe Report builder macro for multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, adobe-analytics, reportbuilder

I came accross a problem here this week. In my case I try to update report builder via macro and then refresh the file to update pivots. I want to do this for multiple workbooks.

I used this macro:

```
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Dim addIn As COMAddIn
Dim automationObject As Object
Dim success As String
Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ReportBuilderAddIn.Connect")
Set automationObject = addIn.Object
success = automationObject.RefreshAllRequests(ActiveWorkbook)
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

Sheets("Week on week 2015").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Range("F8").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
```

It seems the second Application.Wait is screwing the whole macro up. When I don't use the second Application.Wait the issue is that the RefreshAll will start too early while Report Builder is still running. The first file will close and save while the second file opens. This won't work due to the fact that the first file still hass Report Builder running.

Conclusion: 
Does anyone know a better way to wait/pauze the macro while Report Builder can finish it's update? 
Or does anyone know how to call the success line and activate a second part of the macro by identifying the completion of the succesline?

Answer (score 0):

I found a line that could prove a solution. The Report Builder excel plug-in finishes it's work but unfortunately I get an error

Line:

> Threading.thread.Sleep (60000)

Error:

> object required 424

VBA used:

```
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
Application.CommandBars("Adobe Report Builder Toolbar").Controls(5).Execute
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:010"))
Threading.thread.Sleep (60000)

Sheets("Week on week 2015").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Range("F8").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?